# How to instantiate object in aspx page one time for hits to share

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple aspx page.
I need to instantiate a class object myObj one time on first hit. On subsequent hits from clients the same object needs to be used.
I am reading a file from local drive when obj is created and also maintaining some state. On subsequent hits I want object to be not created but states to be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I would cache the obj on `Application_Start()` in the `global.asax`.

Just be certain you're persisting state after each hit.

Comment: If I create and cache the obj in application_start, how would I access that obj in lets say Default.aspx page under <% %>

Comment: Just to be clear, its is not a counter. clients are sending some info and I am marking them these info have received. If there is a duplicate I am sending duplicate reply.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Caching Objects](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/caching/object-caching/) article to get started. Keep in mind, if you are making changes to the object it can be dangerous due to multi-user collisions so it's best to use the cache for data that you need to reference a lot. A list of states, text strings used throughout, settings, etc. that don't change but you need everywhere are perfect items for the cache.